# docker mysql Exception:Can anyone see the root cause in logs

Tags: mysql, docker

It is normal when the project is deployed locally.
Exception shows up when i am trying to deploy on ESC server by using docker

**Here is logs**

2022-06-14 09:10:51.319  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-06-14 09:10:52.337 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]...............

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    ... 121 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    ... 124 common frames omitted
2022-06-14 09:10:52.358 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
### The error may exist in com/llj/dao/CategoryDao.java (best guess)
### The error may involve com.llj.dao.CategoryDao.findAllCategory
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.] with root cause
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111]................................................
```

**Here is docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /root/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /root/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    privileged: true
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.27
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
  wallpaper:
    image: wallpaper:latest
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
```

**Here is Dockerfile**

```
FROM java:8

EXPOSE 8080

ADD Wallpaper-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar","--spring.profiles.active=pro"]
```

**Here is application-pro.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/wallpaper?useUnicode=true&useSSL=false&characterEncoding=utf8&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai
    username: root
    password: xxxxxx
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 30MB  
      max-request-size: 100MB 

pagehelper:
  helper-dialect: mysql

shiro-redis:
  enable: true
  redis-manger:
    host: redis:6379
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Wallpaper` to be your application, ther error is your `mysql` container never booted up.

If you are trying to access from an external application, you cant use dns `mysql` in application properties, instead use the IP exposed by ECS or whatever LB you have attached infront of it.

Like

```
    url: jdbc:mysql://myecsip:3306/wallpaper?useUnicode=true&useSSL=false&characterEncoding=utf8&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai
```

If you still find no luck in figuring mysql issue, can you post the container logs of your mysql?

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: What is the issue now? any insights?

Comment: It is normal for me to use Navicat to connect toMySQL container

Comment: how are you connecting mysql to your navicat?

Comment: just new connection，input my ECS Server IP,port,root,password

Comment: Yeah so it will work the same , considering the machine running docker has internet connectivity.

Comment: So why “Wallpaper” can't connect MySQL.       url,username,password is correct,I'm confused QAQ

Comment: It cant connect because your Mysql is not up. I gave it a try in my local, this compose works fine

Comment: MySQL is not up？But After "docker ps"is entered, it show the MySQL container is running

Comment: of course, my "wallpeper","nginx","redis" container all running

Comment: I am trying to say, that your mysql didnt successfully bootup.

Comment: How do I check whether MySQL is successfully bootup

Comment: Sorry, I'm a novice

Comment: you mean ?                                                                            [root@iZwz9i109h0ol61x0lnxe8Z ~]# `docker exec -it root_mysql_1 /bin/bash`
root@05276136f57a:/#`service mysql start`
[info]`A MySQL Server is already started.`